# Avoid being bitten by a contaminated namespace

Tags: python, namespaces

I just spent almost an hour tracking down what was- at the time- a very confusing error message. The source of the error was this block of code (for the purposes of this question, the meaning of all the pieces really doesn't matter):

```
fspec_prsrs = tuple(compile('{{{}{}}}'.format(fstr_tup.field_name
                                                if fstr_tup.field_name else '',
                                              ':'+fstr_tup.format_spec
                                                if fstr_tup.format_spec else ''
                                              )
                            )
                    for fstr_tup in fstr_tuples)
```

Which resulted in this error:

```
*** TypeError: Required argument 'filename' (pos 2) not found
```

The cause of the error is that I had neglected to do an import of the `compile` function at the top of the file (from the [`parse` module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/parse)).

As a result, `compile` is referring to the [built-in `compile` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#compile). Although the error message seems very clear to me now that I understand the cause, I ended up wasting a bunch of time looking at the package source code from which *thought* I had imported the function, thinking the error was coming from there. Instead, it was coming from the built-in `compile` all along.

The `compile` function is something I tend to forget even exists. I hardly ever use it, if ever, and indeed there are a number of functions in the built-in list just like `compile` that I also never use (I'm looking at **YOU**, [`id`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id), and ***YOU***, [filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter)!), and as a result they are sitting there doing nothing other than contaminating my namespace.

Typically when forgetting to import something, one will just get a `NameError` in which case the cause is obvious; but when there are things lurking about in the namespace I did not put there it is much less obvious. Is there a full-proof way to avoid issues like this?

What can be done? Or is this just something every Python coder has to learn to live with?

Comment: Perhaps use an IDE that highlights built-in names? That way, it'll be clear if you're code refers to a built-in name. Pycharm does this. As well as Sublime.

Comment: @ChristianDean Since I have never regularly used an IDE that solution wasn't obvious to me, though I'm sure it probably seems obvious to people who have. I have generally said "I don't need an IDE" (I just use Notepad++) but I suppose tonight I have proven that I do.

Answer (score 2):

The only idea I have that avoids this problem is to not import objects into the namespace to begin with. For example, instead of:

```
from parse import compile
```

One would do:

```
import parse
parse.compile(...)
```

This fixes the problem. However, I do not like this solution because the only thing I plan to use from the `parse` package in that module is `compile` in the first place. It is a bit more direct and clear to the reader (i.e., Future Me) *WHY* and *WHAT* I am making use of the `parse` module when what is being imported is right up front.

A better solution would be a "set it and forget" way to eliminate things from the global namespace that aren't of use to me in the module in which I'm working.

Comment: would `from parse import compile as <some unique name>` be suitable for the understanding of future you?

Comment: @Eric i don't know... future me is pretty stupid. it's a good suggestion in general but my complaint would be that in order *remember* i need to do that, i would need to be mindful- *today*- of the bulit-in namespace pollution in the first place... lack of this mindfulness was the source of the problem to begin with.

Comment: `from <module> import <function>` is a pattern that is relatively easy to grep, so you could automatically scan your code for this kind of aberration. Or you could even write a plugin for [Pylint](https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/how_tos/plugins.html).

Comment: @Eric that sounds like a really workable solution- thanks!